# SharePoint 2007->2013 Pre-Upgrade Checker Question; Customized list views that will not be upgraded

Tags: 2007, list-view, custom-list, upgrade

We're planning on upgrading our SharePoint environment from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013.  We recently ran the pre-upgrade checker and received a lot of *information only* listings under **Customized list views that will not be upgraded**.  My basic question is, *what should I do with these*?

The list contains a lot of lists.  They all seem to be custom lists, but the views associated with some of these lists do not seem to have been modified at all...they're still using the basic All Items view.  When I look inside, there is no CAML statements, no filters, no groupings, no sorting other than the default *sort by ID*.

When we make the initial upgrade to SharePoint 2010 (prior to going to 2013), will we have to go into everyone of these lists and create a new view so that the new XSLT-based list view will be used?  Is that why Microsoft is trying to get across in their [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956450)?

Here is a small sample of what is reported:

```
Information Only : Customized list views that will not be upgraded. 
A list view using custom Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML), a list view not associated with a Feature, or a list view associated with a custom Feature, will not be upgraded to the new XSLT-based list view. A list view that is not upgraded will still render properly in Windows SharePoint Services 4.0, but it will not inherit any benefits of the new XSLT-based list view, such as SharePoint Designer customization support, conditional formatting and improved developer experience with XSLT standard-based language support. The following list views will not be upgraded: 
• 0adbde27-c4d0-4732-bc11-61b8ddeddd44-----corporate/gov/Lists/lad/AllItems.aspx(All Items)
• 20c2a5f6-051b-4830-9ec8-13ee14cef346-----corporate/gov/Lists/lcc/AllItems.aspx(All Responses)
• 880a3e42-cc57-4a0f-9ed5-5981fc0f7747-----corporate/gov/Lists/galt/AllItems.aspx(All Items)
```

Comment: I do believe you're right. From my experience in MOSS migrations, those views work fine, but they don't use the new XsltListViewWebPart. Let's see what others have to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed with the comments about the lists working, just won't use the new features and functionality.

BTW, this is an old post, but you have likely learned that you cannot go directly from 2007 to 2013. You must stop off at 2010, use a third party migration tool (or write your own), or manually migrate content.

Just an FYI in-case anyone else comes across this post.